# Align poem attribution with right side of versewidth rather than with right side ofpage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, poetry

I would like to add attributions to some poems in memoir.  The below code does that but flushes the attributions with the right of the text block.  I would like them to flush with the right of the verse width.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
  \vskip2ex\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{``This boy is forest-born.''}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
``This boy is forest-born.''\\
\attrib{\textit{-- As You Like It}}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `\attrib` here can take an optional argument to manually override the `\versewidth`.  Setting the optional argument to `\textwidth` will right-align the attribution relative to the page, as shown in the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\newcommand{\attrib}[2][\versewidth]{%
  \vskip2ex\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize%
  #2\hspace{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\dimexpr#1}\mbox{}\par}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{``This boy is forest-born.''}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
``This boy is forest-born.''\\
\attrib{\textit{-- As You Like It}}
\end{verse}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{``This boy is forest-born blah blah.''}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
``This boy is forest-born blah blah.''\\
\attrib{\textit{-- As You Like It}}
\end{verse}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{``Override the default attib placement.''}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
``Override the default attib placement.''\\
\attrib[\textwidth]{\textit{-- As You Like It}}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]